# ZF2 error 404 when child_routes

Tags: php, routes, zend-framework2

This is my last chance. I tried loooking for answers, but seriously, I can't see what I'm doing wrong...
I'm trying to set up a multi-domain on a website. 
Everything is working fine when using literal routes.
When adding the other domain with Hostname route, still OK.
But when adding child_routes to that Hostname route, the parent route shoots a 404.
Here's my module.config :

```
'resources' => $resources,
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'example.com' => array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Hostname',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '[:subdomain.]:domain.:tld', // domain levels from right to left
                'contraints' => array(
                    'subdomain' => 'www',
                    'domain' => 'example',
                    'tld' => 'com',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                    'controller' => 'Index',
                    'action' => 'itdoc',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'customCatalog2' => array(
                    'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => '/custom-catalog',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'action' => 'customCatalog',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
```

When accessing http://example.com, I'm getting a 404.
But the child route works fine (http://example.com/custom-catalog)
But if I comment out the child_routes (and may_terminate), I can access the root domain

Do you have any clue of what is wrong with my code ?

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test your code and in fact this is weird, but after some test and read the docs here is what i Found.

[This documentaiton help](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html#http-routing-examples) 
^
I looked forward to this component and found in the docs this :

```
'packages.zendframework.com' => array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Hostname',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => ':4th.[:3rd.]:2nd.:1st', // domain levels from right to left
                'contraints' => array(
                    '4th' => 'packages',
                    '3rd' => '.*?', // optional 3rd level domain such as .ci, .dev or .test
                    '2nd' => 'zendframework',
                    '1st' => 'com',
                ),
                // Purposely omit default controller and action
                // to let the child routes control the route match
            ),
            // child route controllers may span multiple modules as desired
            'child_routes' => array(
                'index' => array(
                    'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => '/',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'Package\Controller\Index',
                            'action' = > 'index',
                        ),
                    ),
                    'may_terminate' => true,
                ),
            ),
        ),
```

As you can see, they have child route but the first route declared is the route match this pattern : `'/'`, this is your main route you have to declare this equal to your code below :

```
'defaults' => array(
                '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                'controller' => 'Index',
                'action' => 'itdoc',
            ),
```

After that, your main route is correct and you can continue with other child route, just the hostname is not the actual main route `'/'`.

Comment: Yes ! 
Thank you Hooli !

I supposed by having "defaults" section it'd work.
I did try the doc example, but probably changed that "/" route to a child.

Hope this will help others to clarify how child_route works.